# LDAP installation error

Tags: node.js

when i try to npm install ldapauth, it displays many errors. I spend the last 2 days checking for a solution but nothing. I tried to uninstall/ reinstall node & npm, same with node-gyp, and still got the error and also installed python but still getting below error :

i am getting error in console like this :

```
C:\Ruby24-x64\Files\MDash>npm install ldapauth

> buffertools@1.1.0 install C:\Ruby24-x64\Files\MDash\node_modules\buffertools
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Ruby24-x64\Files\MDash\node_modules\buffertools>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error
MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK vers
ion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Ruby24-x64\F
iles\MDash\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Ruby24-x64\Files\MDash\node_modules\buffertools
gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN minovate@1.2.0 No description
npm WARN minovate@1.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN minovate@1.2.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! buffertools@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the buffertools@1.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\miracle\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-06T14_44_34_406Z-debug.log
```

can you help me.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you miss something : `MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found.` You may need to install microsoft visual c++ http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

try to follow the option 1 from this procedure https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows